# Handling knockout text that contains string and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a working application and now I am moving it to mobile version. I am using all the services already created for web. So using these services I sometimes get text something like this.

```
var serverString = 'like this image <img src="abc.png">'
```

When i assign it to knockout property

```
self.PropertyName(serverString)
```

And bind it, it produces this string.

```
like this image <img src="abc.png">
```

I want the text to be read by mobile server or web server so the text remains same but tag convert to tag instead of displaying tag as tag it should display tag as image.
How can I do that?

Here is my binding

```
<p data-bind="text:PropertyName"></p>
```

Comment: Show also your binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html

**Purpose**

The html binding causes the associated DOM element to display the HTML specified by your parameter.

Typically this is useful when values in your view model are actually strings of HTML markup that you want to render.

```
<div data-bind="html: details"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        details: ko.observable() // Initially blank
    };
    viewModel.details("<em>For further details, view the report <a href='report.html'>here</a>.</em>"); // HTML content appears
</script>
```

Comment: ok thanks i have tested and it is wokring fine. I found all i need to use is html instead of text. I assumed tha t i will have to do something else. never thought it works like this. Thanks again.

Comment: Do heed, though, the warning at the end of the documentation page; you need at the very least to make sure the data you're receiving doesn't have any `script` tags, since that would make you vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks.